# Question about Prop 7.31 in Milne's Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

The statement of the Proposition is this. Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, and $\pi$ a generator of its maximal ideal. Let $f(X)\in A[X]$ and $a_0$ be a simple root of $f(X)$ mod $\pi$. Then there is a unique root $a$ of $f(X)$ with $a\equiv a_0$ mod $\pi$.

To prove this, he constructs a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ in $A$, where $f(a_n)\equiv0$ mod $\pi^{n+1}$. From this he concludes that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to a unique limit $a$ with $f(a)=0$, with $a\equiv a_0$ mod $\pi$. I don't see how we can conclude that the $a_n$ converge, or that the limit is $\equiv a_0$ mod $\pi$, or that such an $a$ would be unique.

https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf These are the notes. Thanks.

Comment: $a_{n + 1} - a_n \in (\pi^{n+1})$ so the difference is $\pi$-adically close to $0$. You can make this precise to prove that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction $a_{n+1} \equiv a_n \pmod{\pi^{n+1}}$. In the $\pi$-adic topology this means that $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ get closer and closer together as $n$ increases. In other words, the sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. Finally, remember that the space $A$ is complete, hence every Cauchy sequence is convergent. The uniqueness of the limit follows as the space is also Hausdorff.

Comment: I just noticed the assumption that $A$ is complete. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is Hensel lemma. A univariate polynomial has a simple root modulo a prime number $p$, then this root can be lifted to a unique root modulo any higher power of $p$. You just need to change $p$ to $\pi$. Complete details for this are available at

See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The post is clearly written and answers the question in its utmost generality. It is extremely unprofessional to mark the correct answer down.